# facebook share not working via mobile

Tags: facebook

I want to share a link on facebook ,

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=Testing&p[url]=http://youtu.be/kOoKAbk_Wt4&p[summary]=yoursummaryhere">Click to Share</a>
```

Its working perfectly for web, but when I browse via any mobile(android,ios) it redirect to fb timeline but doesnot show/post anything .

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<a href="javascript:test()">Click here</a>
<script>
function test(){
window.open("http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=YOURappID&link=linkToYourApps&caption=Watch%20our%20Ice%20Breaking%20Machine%20on%20You%20Tube%20%20%20%20%20Discover=yourComments&description=YourDescription&redirect_uri=redirect_url","_parent"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this ?m2w parameter to sharer.php.

In your case:

http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?m2w&s=100&p[url]=ENCODEDURL&p[title]=encoded TITLE&p[summary]=encoded description&p[images][0]=encoded